# Getting particular Case details along with all activities

Tags: acumatica

With `CR306000SetSchema` and `CR306000Submit`, I can create a new Case. But if I want to get details of the particular case with its activities then. Any one has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `CR306000Export` to get the data. Below code sample will get you the activity of particular case ID. For instance "000001" in example below.

```
            string[][] export = context.CR306000Export
            (
                new CaseAPI.Command[]
                {
                    new CaseAPI.Value
                    {
                        Value = "000001",
                        LinkedCommand = CR306000.CaseSummary.CaseID
                    },
                    CR306000.Activities.Type,
                    CR306000.Activities.Summary,
                    CR306000.Details.Description,
                    CR306000.Activities.Status,
                    CR306000.Activities.StartDate,
                    CR306000.CaseSummary.Owner
                },
                new CaseAPI.Filter[] 
                {
                    new CaseAPI.Filter
                    {
                        Field = CR306000.Activities.StartDate,
                        Condition = CaseAPI.FilterCondition.GreaterOrEqual,
                        Value = DateTime.Today
                    }
                },
                0, true, true
            );
```

Comment: With above code I can get all the details but I am not able to get the Activities Description. Can anyone help please?